# Latex packages / templates for maths exercises

Tags: math-mode, packages, templates, exercises

I'm enrolled in a mathematics course where we are supposed to return our solutions to weekly exercises as PDF files. There seems not to be any general official guidelines other than "it's legible", e.g. one can take a photo / scan handwritten text, but I want to practise my latex skills.

Could you recommend useful packages, templates and any other resources for producing good-looking and readable exercise answers?

I'm a relatively inexperienced in LaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: Have a look at suggestions made here [Comparing packages which facilitate typesetting exercises and solutions: exercise vs. answers vs. probsoln](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22269/15717)

Comment: I would also take a look at [`exam`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam). I actually use that package (actually a document class, like `article`) *all the time* to typeset my homework, and it works wonderfully and looks professional.

Comment: There's also [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets)

Comment: Check the [`handin`](https://ctan.org/pkg/handin) package.