# Adding text to a different part of the document

Tags: sectioning, theorems, automation

I'm writing a LaTeX document at the moment which has problems (which are created in a `{theorem}` environment) for the reader in it. I'd like to put solutions to those problems in the end of the document. Of course, I could just add another section/chapter called “solutions” in the end and write them there. But, since the problems are very likely to be reordered and new problems will be added I would have to change the order of the solutions manually which could be quite a hassle. I was wondering whether it is possible to write LaTeX code in some part of the document which then appears in a different part of the final document. Ideally I would like to write something like

```
\begin{problem} \label{someProblem}
Here is some problem.
\end{problem}
\addTextToTheSolutionsChapter{
Solution to problem \ref{someProblem}
}
```

which typesets the problem right in place and appends the text in the parentheses to the section in the back.

Comment: You can do this with the `answers` package. Solution text goes with the exercise and is written to an external file. Close that file and then `\include` it just before `\end{document}`. Renumbering takes care of itself.

Comment: You would find the [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) package really useful for producing your document. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you both very much! I tried the 'answers' package and it looks very much like what I need.

Comment: Could we close this as a duplicate of [Comparing packages which facilitate typesetting exercises and solutions: exercise vs. answers vs. probsoln](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22269)?

Comment: Another solution using `recording` macros from `tcolorbox` can be found in [How to defer content to a later part of the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224429/1952)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I read the question, I first thought of an external file, which is somehow a standard solution. But, with the macro design, you proposed, this is not necessary. A possible (and possibly the most simple but not the fastest -- see the answer of @egreg) implementation with a small test could like like:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[chapter]

\makeatletter
\def\solutionsname{Solutions}
\let\@sol=\@empty
\newcommand{\printsolutions}[1][chapter]{\@nameuse{#1}{\solutionsname}\@sol}
\newcommand{\addtosolutions}[1]{%
  \protected@xdef\@sol{%
    \@sol {\noindent\bfseries\theproblem}\space#1\par\vskip 1em plus 4pt minus 4pt\par
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Groups}

\begin{problem}
Let $(G,\circ)$ be a finite group and $g\in G$. Prove that the order of $g$ divides the cardinality of $G$.
\addtosolutions{%
  Because $G$ is finite there is $\operatorname{ord}_G(g)=:m<\infty$. Hence, there exists a cyclic subgroup $U_g=\lbrace e,g,g^2,\ldots,g^{m-1}\rbrace$. Obviously $\lvert U_g\rvert=m=\operatorname{ord}_G(g)$ holds. Therefore the claim follows from Lagrange theorem.
}
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
Let $(G,\circ)$ be a group. Show that $m\circ G=G\quad\forall m\in G$.
\addtosolutions{%
  The inclusion $m\circ G\subseteq G$ is evident due to the closure of $\circ$ on $G$. Let $m,n\in G$. By calculating
  \[
    n=e\circ n=(m\circ m^{-1})\circ n=m\circ(m^{-1}\circ n)\in m\in G,
  \]
  we obtain $G\subseteq m\circ G$.
}
\end{problem}

\appendix
\printsolutions
\end{document}
```

The synopsis is exactly as described in the OP: (1) `\addtosolutions` gathers the solution inside the `problem` environment and (2) the solutions will be printed with the `\printsolutions` macro at the point you want them to be. (`\printsolutions` can be called with an optional argument that sets the sectioning level in terms of the sectioning command; default: 'chapter'.)

Note that the `\appendix` call in my example can be dropped. I just find it well suited for this situation.

Comment: Why defining `\csname sol\thesol\endcsname` when you expand it in the next stage? Add `\protected` before `\expandafter`, to store in `\@sol` only the control sequence and not its expansion. I wouldn't use `\vspace*` because it won't disappear at a page break, which is instead wanted.

Comment: @egreg: This must come from a previous implementation I designed with a slightly different aim. What the code does now, can be acomplished way easier. I will deal with it tomorrow. (At least it is still a working solution.) The `\vspace*` of course should be `\vspace`...

Comment: Thanks @egreg! Note that by tomorrow I meant 649 days... ;)

Answer (score 7):

This is a variation on Ruben's solution that uses a token register instead of relying on `\protected@xdef` (it should be a bit faster). The main difference is that no expansion is done on the argument to `\solution`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}[chapter]
\providecommand\solutionsname{Solutions}

\makeatletter
\newtoks\@soltoks
\newcommand\printsolutions[1][\solutionsname]{%
  \chapter{#1}
  \the\@soltoks}
\newcommand\solution[1]{%
  \edef\@soltemp{%
    \the\@soltoks % the previously stored solutions
    \noexpand\solutionpreamble{\theproblem}% we only want \theproblem to be expanded
    \unexpanded{#1}%
  }
  \global\@soltoks=\expandafter{\@soltemp}
}
\newcommand{\solutionpreamble}[1]{%
  \par\medskip\noindent\textbf{#1}\enspace\ignorespaces
}
\makeatother

%A small test
\begin{document}
\chapter{Groups}

\begin{problem}
Let $(G,\circ)$ be a finite group and $g\in G$. Prove that the order
of $g$ divides the cardinality of $G$.

\solution{Because $G$ is finite there is $\operatorname{ord}_G(g)=:m<\infty$.
  Hence, there exists a cyclic subgroup $U_g=\lbrace e,g,g^2,\ldots,g^{m-1}\rbrace$. 
  Obviously $\lvert U_g\rvert=m=\operatorname{ord}_G(g)$ holds. Therefore the
  claim follows from Lagrange theorem.}
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
Let $(G,\circ)$ be a group. Show that $m\circ G=G\quad\forall m\in G$.
\solution{The inclusion $m\circ G\subseteq G$ is evident due to the
  closure of $\circ$ on $G$. Let $m,n\in G$. By calculating
  \[
  n=e\circ n=(m\circ m^{-1})\circ n=m\circ(m^{-1}\circ n)\in m\in G,
  \]
  we obtain $G\subseteq m\circ G$.}
\end{problem}

\printsolutions
\end{document}
```

One can type `\printsolutions[Solutions of selected exercises]` instead of modifying the standard `\solutionsname`. The formatting of the solutions can be defined in the macro `\solutionpreamble` that takes as argument the problem number.