# What is a better way to link questions and answers on a problem sheet?

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, lists

I write many problem sheets. The basic structure is thus:

```
\section{Questions}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Question 1
        \item Question 2
        \item Question 3
    \end{enumerate}
\section{Answers}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Answer to Question 1
        \item Answer to Question 2
        \item Answer to Question 3
    \end{enumerate}
```

Matching questions and answers becomes very time-consuming when I have to add a question, or make a question into a multi-part question with nested `enumerate` environments. It strikes me that this must be a problem that someone has already solved, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Packages `exsheets`, `probsln`, `answers`, `exam` etc. all provide this, in a more or less easy way, with different features. The CTAN archive is worth looking into it ;-)

Comment: The [`exam`](http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/exam/examdoc.pdf) class is great, but as it has been asked [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/292669/64454), there is no native way to append append a solution sheet. It only prints questions and, if needed, the respective answer below.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140943/adding-text-to-a-different-part-of-the-document/141021#141021

Comment: Another solution with `tcolorbox`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224429/1952