# What is the most practical method to write a book of math or physics problems?

Tags: chapters, input, books

My main problem is the following. I would like to put the problems and their solutions together into separate input files. In the source code I would like to switch easily between two modes. In mode 1 the solution of a problem follows the problem itself. In mode 2 there is a separate chapter for solutions at the end of the book. It is possible to solve this problem with the usage of a short predefined command between the problem and the solution in each input files and nothing else?

Comment: Something like the [answer](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/answers) package perhaps?

Comment: I think you could use [How to defer content to a later part of the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224408) to modify it for your own requirements.

Answer (score 5):

The package `exsheets` meets all your requirements.

You have two environments, 'question' and  'solution '. You can choose whether you want to print the answers and where. You can give IDs and include from external files by them. The appearance is very customizable.

Have a look into the documentation: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exsheets/exsheets_en.pdf

Comment: exsheets sounds good, however a begin-end block is not the most simple solution, is it possible to do with only one command between the 'question' and the 'solution' in the input files?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, you want to spare 1 line of code?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use only source text in the input files, and as little code as possible, and not environments

Comment: Why? Could you elaborate on that?  That does not aound like a good idea to me and clearly  not like a reasonable restriction.

Comment: And what about exsol? which is the best?

Comment: @user3058699 »the best« is highly subjective. This question and its answers might be of interest to you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22269/ (I don't understand why you don't like environments here: they really seem to be the natural (LaTeX) choice. (It can't be the typing: many editors have auto-completion for environments...)