# List of equations, including equation contents and caption

Tags: table-of-contents, equations, content-replication, etoc

I would like to automatically generate a list of equations present in the document, which includes the *equation* itself. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\caption#1{}
\begin{document}
First Euler observed that
\begin{equation}
1 + e^{i \Pi} = 0.
\caption{Euler's equation tying together the five fundamental constants of mathematics}
\end{equation}

Then, Gauss discovered the normal distribution:
\begin{equation}
P(x) = \frac{1}{{\sigma \sqrt {2\pi } }}e^{{{ - \left( {x - \mu } \right)^2 } \mathord{\left/ {\vphantom {{ - \left( {x - \mu } \right)^2 } {2\sigma ^2 }}} \right. \kern-\nulldelimiterspace} {2\sigma ^2 }}}
\caption{Normal distribution}
\end{equation}

Finally, Einstein proclaimed: 
\begin{equation}
E = m C^2
\caption{Equivalence of mass and energy}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Here is an example of how the output might look, but any other format may be fine; it would of course be nice to have hyperref links, page numbers, etc, but these are not essential.

```
\section*{List of equations}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Euler's equation tying together the five fundamental constants of mathematics
        \[
          1 + e^{i \Pi} = 0.
        \]
  \item Normal distribution:
        \[
          P(x) = \frac{1}{{\sigma \sqrt {2\pi } }}e^{{{ - \left( {x - \mu } \right)^2 } \mathord{\left/ {\vphantom {{ - \left( {x - \mu } \right)^2 } {2\sigma ^2 }}} \right. \kern-\nulldelimiterspace} {2\sigma ^2 }}}
        \]
  \item Equivalence of mass and energy
        \[
          E = m C^2
        \]
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Are you sure you want to have this in your document?

Comment: Absolutely. I produce course notes for my students, and it would be useful to generate a cheat sheet for them.

Comment: One design possibility: use the `environ` package to wrap equations in a `NewEnviron` that writes its `BODY` both to the current document and an external file. At the end of your document, `input` some macros to change the behavior of the saved `BODY` and input the external file. You could then produce your cheatsheet as a separate document if you wished.

Comment: @EthanBolker Technically prett close to: [How to defer content to a later part of the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224408) Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer based on `extract` environment sounded really promising and elegant, but it turned out to be a bit fragile, especially with `beamerarticle`. At times it was fussy for apparently no reason until spaces prior to the `\begin{equation}` where changed.

Here is an alternative using the `environ` package. Here is how is used:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}
\title{Demo of \texttt{generate-list-equations}}
\author{Yogi the bear}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{generate-list-of-equations}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Start with a list of all equations}
\listofequations

\section{Main matters}
People say that \begin{equation}1+1=2\end{equation} but how do we know that this is true?

First, Euler observed that
\begin{equation}
  1 + e^{i \pi} = 0.
  \synopsis{Euler's equation tying together the five fundamental constants of mathematics}%
\end{equation}
Then, Gauss discovered the normal distribution:
\begin{equation}
  P(x) = \frac{1}{{\sigma \sqrt {2\pi }}} e^{-\frac{(x - \mu)^2} {2 \sigma^2}}
  \synopsis{Normal distribution}%
\end{equation}
Finally, Einstein proclaimed:
\begin{equation}
  E = m C^2
  \synopsis{Equivalnce of mass and energy}
\end{equation}

Only then, it became clear that 
\begin{equation}
  2 + 2 = 4
  \synopsis{Two and two before!}
\end{equation}

\section{The END}
That's all folks!
\section{PS. The list of equations can be placed anywhere}
\listofequations
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Here is the actual code; it is written in an `.sty` file, but it is not polished enough to be considered a package yet. If you need to use it, it is likely that you would need to tweak it.

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{environ}

% The main command generates a list of equations by
% simply \input ting `\jobname.leq`
\newcommand\listofequations{%
  \IfFileExists{\jobname.leq}{\input{\jobname.leq}}{\relax}
}

% File "\jobname.eqn" collects all equations
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newwrite\equationsListFile
  \immediate\openout\equationsListFile=\jobname.eqn%
  \immediate\write\equationsListFile{\unexpanded{\begingroup\description}}
  \immediate\write\equationsListFile{
    \unexpanded{\def\synopsis}
    \hashchar
    \unexpanded{1{}}
  }
  \immediate\write\equationsListFile{\unexpanded{\setlength{\itemsep}{2pt}}}
  \immediate\write\equationsListFile{\unexpanded{\abovedisplayskip=3pt plus 3pt minus 2pt}}
  \immediate\write\equationsListFile{\unexpanded{\belowdisplayskip=2pt plus 3pt minus 2pt}}
}

% Copy "\jobname.eqn" to "\jobname.leq"
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\equationsListFile{\unexpanded{\enddescription\endgroup}}
  \immediate\closeout\equationsListFile
  \newread\in
  \openin\in=\jobname.eqn
  \newwrite\out
  \immediate\openout\out\jobname.leq
  \endlinechar-1
  \loop \unless\ifeof\in
  \readline\in to\l
  \immediate\write\out{\l}
  \repeat
  \immediate\closeout\out
  \closein\in
}

% Save previous \begin{equation} and \end{equation} commands:
\let\beginEquation=\equation
\let\endEquation=\endequation

% Undefine them, so that that the environment can be redefined:
\providecommand*\@nameundef[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname #1\endcsname\@undefined
}
\@nameundef{equation}
\@nameundef{endequation}

\NewEnviron{equation}{{%
  % Default equation name is empty:
  \gdef\equationName{}
  % Let the synposis command record the equation's name
  \def\synopsis##1{\gdef\equationName{##1}}
  % Generate equation in document as usual (but hook on \labe)
  \beginEquation
  \BODY
  \label{eq:\theequation}
  \endEquation
  \@onelevel@sanitize\BODY
  \@onelevel@sanitize\equationName
  % Generate an entry in \jobname.leq (tweak as necessary)
  \immediate\write\equationsListFile{\unexpanded{\pagebreak[3]}}
  \immediate\write\equationsListFile{\unexpanded{\item}}
  \immediate\write\equationsListFile{[(\unexpanded{\ref}{eq:\theequation})]}
  \immediate\write\equationsListFile{\equationName\unexpanded{~~\dotfill~~}\thepage}
  \immediate\write\equationsListFile{\unexpanded{\nopagebreak[3]}}
  \immediate\write\equationsListFile{\unexpanded{\\\begin{equation*}}}
  \immediate\write\equationsListFile{\BODY}
  \immediate\write\equationsListFile{\unexpanded{\end{equation*}}}
}}

% globally defines a macro \hashchar which holds a verbatim `#`
\begingroup
\catcode`\#=12
\gdef\hashchar{#}%
\endgroup
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you want a cheat sheet, I'd recommend the [`extract`](http://ctan.org/pkg/extract) package. With a slightly different MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  active,
  header=false,
  copydocumentclass=true,
  generate=\jobname-Cheatsheet,
  extract-env={equation},
  extract-cmdline={synopsis},
  ]{extract} % http://ctan.org/pkg/extract
\begin{extract*}
% Items executed in both the main and extracted document
% (extract manual, section 5.1)
\usepackage{amsmath}
\end{extract*}
\begin{extract}
% Items executed only in extracted document
\def\synopsis#1{#1}
\end{extract}
\def\synopsis#1{}
\begin{document}
First Euler observed that
\synopsis{Euler's equation tying together the five fundamental constants of mathematics}%
\begin{equation}
1 + e^{i \Pi} = 0.
\end{equation}

Then, Gauss discovered the normal distribution:
\synopsis{Normal distribution}%
\begin{equation}
P(x) = \frac{1}{{\sigma \sqrt {2\pi } }}e^{{{ - \left( {x - \mu } \right)^2 } \mathord{\left/ {\vphantom {{ - \left( {x - \mu } \right)^2 } {2\sigma ^2 }}} \right. \kern-\nulldelimiterspace} {2\sigma ^2 }}}
\end{equation}

Finally, Einstein proclaimed: 
\synopsis{Equivalence of mass and energy}%
\begin{equation}
E = m C^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

you get an original document of:

[image]

and an extracted document of:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Items executed in both the main and extracted document
% (extract manual, section 5.1)
\usepackage{amsmath}
% Items executed only in extracted document
\def\synopsis#1{#1}

\begin{document}

\synopsis{Euler's equation tying together the five fundamental constants of mathematics}%

\begin{equation}
1 + e^{i \Pi} = 0.
\end{equation}

\synopsis{Normal distribution}%

\begin{equation}
P(x) = \frac{1}{{\sigma \sqrt {2\pi } }}e^{{{ - \left( {x - \mu } \right)^2 } \mathord{\left/ {\vphantom {{ - \left( {x - \mu } \right)^2 } {2\sigma ^2 }}} \right. \kern-\nulldelimiterspace} {2\sigma ^2 }}}
\end{equation}

\synopsis{Equivalence of mass and energy}%

\begin{equation}
E = m C^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

and:

[image]

This also works with your original `\caption` command.

Comment: Elegant indeed!

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you to look into the [`float` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/float), with it comes the command `\listof` that can be used to generate lists of self defined floating environments.

You may then define your own equation environment and use the `\listof` command to generate a list of equations.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{myequation}{H}{eq}[section]
\floatname{myequation}{Equation}
\begin{document}
\listof{myequation}{List of Equations}
\section{First Section}
First Euler observed that
\begin{myequation}
\begin{equation}
1 + e^{i \Pi} = 0.
\end{equation}
\caption{Euler's equation tying together the five fundamental constants of mathematics}
\end{myequation}
\end{document}
```

However now the equation caption is numbered as well as the equation so you may want to use the stard version of the `equation` environment to generate your inner equation, so to suppress the numbering of the inner equation. The `equation*` environment may be found in the `amsmath` package.

Inclusion of the actual equation in the list of equations may be hacked using the optional parameter to the `\caption` command like this:

```
\caption[$$1 + e^{i \Pi} = 0$$]{caption part not to be included in the list of equations}
```

However, if the equation spans more than one line, like say a fraction, this method does not work...

Answer (score 0):

I found this. Easy peasy! I just need to figure out how to make the heading style match with the rest of the lists in my document, but am holding onto hope!

https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=428

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}

\listofmyequations

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Eq1}
   a=b
\end{equation}
\myequations{Equation number \ref{eq:Eq1}}

\newpage

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Eq2}
   b=c
\end{equation}
\myequations{Equation number \ref{eq:Eq2}}

\end{document}
```