# Can you have a bibliography of equations?

Tags: bibliographies, amsmath

I am creating revision notes for a Mathematics module at university and I was wondering if there was a way to take all of the equations that I have written throughout the document and have them all appear at the bottom of the document. A kind of bibliography or index of equations.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome into the community of TeX.SE.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224756/35864