# Use a class as a package? (or parts of the class)

Tags: exam, exercises

Is there a way to get some of the functionality of a class without the document being based on that class?

I use the `exam` class a good bit to typeset exams and problem sets. I'm trying to format a book (still not sure whether `book`, `amsbook`, `tufte-book`, or whatever class) and I'd like to include exercises. It seems (maybe just because I'm used to it) that the `exam` class handles exercises in the way I would like, so I'd really like to use its tools for setting up questions and answers, but I don't want the entire book to be in the `exam` class.

Comment: You can copy the relevant code into your own `.sty` file and just load that.

Comment: You can copy parts of the class code (but mind the copyright issue) to a package or preamble of your own -- the exam.cls is based on article.cls, so it's possible to keep most of the `exercise` specific stuff, but this requires a check. Some classes define importer `.sty` files to provide the functionality without adapting the outer class features. In principle, any package can modify the outer class behaviour

Comment: The greatest problem in my point of view would be the class options which drive the exam macros behaviour (somehow). You should specify what should be used from `exam.cls` at all

Comment: you can save `exam.cls` as `myexam.sty` change line `\ProvidesClass{exam}` into `\ProvidesPackage{myexam}` then delete line `\LoadClass{article}` I think this will be fine.

Comment: @touhami: Not quite -- the options aren't handled correctly (in my point of view) and there are a lot of geometry related settings done in `exam.cls` which are still active unless `\usepackage{geometry}` is used with a `store/save` way.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't think so, no problem with options. Indeed the margins and text area are changed but I think `geometry` package is universal now a day so one can load it after `myexam` and set the margins proprely. in my point of view the important problem is related to somefeature that oblige the user to use `questions` environment only once by document.

Comment: @touhami: Yes, but perhaps that restriction could be patched out. But the question itself isn't very clear so far

Comment: @touhami: You deleted the link ;-) Well, in fact together with that link and the `geometry` package it's much better to keep `exam.cls` as the underlying class as long as `\chapter` isn't needed

Comment: What exavtly do you need? The exam class takes care of automated headers (not needed that way in a book), summing up points of a sheet (not needed that way in a book), hiding/printing of answers (not needed that way in a book) and numbering questions (very, very easy). You can have a look at packages `exsheets` and `tasks` that might be handy for your project. I don't see any point i fiddling with `exam` here, it will be a constant head-ache for you.

Comment: @Johannes_B: There's plenty of stuff in `exam` that I don't care about for the book: points and headers as you point out. I do want questions and answers together rather than in separate files. Since I won't actually want to print them together in the book, `exam` might not be the best way to do that.

The only clear-cut benefits of `exam` over alternatives are: (a) I'm already familiar with it, and (b) It will be easy to share things between the book and exams / problem sets. (b) is actually a pretty big benefit.

Comment: If you want to print questions and answers separatly, you might be interested in [How to defer content to a later part of the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224408) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problems are `\ProvideClass` and `\Loadclass` -- those must be deactivated. Since those are used by `.cls` files only, following `.sty` won't get in trouble.

More work is to be done for the special options (not done yet).

I don't claim this will work in any case!

- `exam.cls` changes several lengths
- `exam.cls` changes page styles

etc.

In principle, it should be possible to catch those changes but perhaps it's really easier to copy the `question` etc. related code to an own `.sty` file (and ask the class author beforehand ;-))

---

`examimport.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{examimport}

\RequirePackage{xparse}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\ProvidesClass}{mO{}}{%
}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\LoadClass}{O{}mO{}}{%
}

\input{examcopy.cls}

\endinput
```

**Driver file** (the example for `\begin{questions}...` is take from the `exam` documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{examimport}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question[10]
Why is there air?
\question[15]
How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck
wood?
\question[10] Compute $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx$.
\end{questions}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It might be polite to ask the author, but there is no need to, that is a basic reason for the LPPL licence (under which exam is distributed) anyone can take any part (or all) of the code and use in another package.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'd be astonished if somebody asked me for permission when they only planned to use the stuff privately. If they were going to publish a derivative, sure - it would be nice to ask, though not, as you say, required - but for personal use? I wouldn't really know how to respond. 'So what?' seems rude!

Comment: @cfr yes agreed, the politeness comment was just a hook to the answer's comment saying that you should ask. The point of my comment was that asking is never necessary.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, I know. I was asserting a somewhat stronger claim: that, for private use, politeness did not require it either.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You know me... I am not polite only if it concerns your packages :-P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thanks! But, sadly, no. It doesn't work. For a barest-bones document it does, but as soon as I put in `\chapter{Introduction}`, it chokes with: `\begin{fullwidth} on input line [line for \chapter] ended by end{list}`.

Comment: @Timothy: `\chapter{Introduction}`  works for me without problems

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Huh! Goes to show I should think more about having a minimal working example. When I used `\class{tufte-book}` I got the error. Using `\class{book}`, I don't. I'll try this out some more, thanks!

Comment: @Timothy: I used `book` (Personally, I am not very fond of `tufte`)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thanks! This seems to be doing the trick nicely.