# Pagebreaking colored boxes inside exercise

Tags: page-breaking

When I try to use `mdframed` box inside `Exercise` enviroment from package `exercise`, the page breaking does not work. It does work if I switch the order - if I use `Exercise` inside a box. I however need the box IN the `Exercise`, and correctly broken. How can I achieve that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newmdenv{mybox}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{Exercise}   %%% Works correctly if I swap these two enviroments
    \begin{mybox}
        \lipsum[1-3]
    \end{mybox}
\end{Exercise}


\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** Well, apparently you get the exact same results with `tcolorbox` and other boxing packages. I am removing `mdframed` from tags and the title, as this is issue with general colored boxes, or something they have in common.

Comment: It would probably be a whole lot easier to fix/replace the exercise package than mdframed.  Parsing the list of keywords seems to be the only complicated thing it does.

Answer (score 2):

I can't offer a full solution (and don't have the rep to comment yet), but my suspicion is that this is caused by the `exercise` package storing the contents of environments in vboxes.  If you have the option, you may have better luck with one of the [other packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22269/comparing-packages-which-facilitate-typesetting-exercises-and-solutions-exercis) for putting together exercise sheets.

The following seems to produce the frame correctly for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
%\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newmdenv{mybox}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{question}
  \begin{mybox}
    \lipsum[1-3]
  \end{mybox}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I knew about other packages, but I've built on top of the `exercise` package quite a lot of code and I would not like to rewrite it using different package.

However, if no other solution will be presented near time, I will accept this as an answer.