# Typesetting of problems and solutions

Tags: typography

I want to typeset my problems and solutions in my coursework. How do you do that keeping in mind that I want both the problem and the solution typeset?

**Questions?**

- What should I use/how to separate the problem statement/question and my solution? (important)
- Does anyone have some really great templates/examples for me?

Comment: see https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/answers or https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam

Comment: Have a look at the packages `exsheets`,  `answers`,  `probsoln`,  `exam`...

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22269/ (sadly this question and its answers don't cover `exsheets`, but…)

Comment: @clemens: Shamelessly promoting your own package :-P

Comment: @ChristianHupfer in a way :) Promoting own packages actually is counterprodutive: the more people use it the more people mail you for support. This is the reason why I *always* mention alternatives

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I want questions and answers in close proximity of each other I tend to use tcolorbox.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Question and Answer]
  This is the question
\tcblower
  This is the answer
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

With tcolorbox it's easy to control many aspects of the upper and lower parts of the box (colors, borders, separators, sizes etc...) which is something I like a lot. I would suggest a look into the manual as well as the examples document at [ctan](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)

Comment: Can your style add in theorem environment?

Comment: @minthao_2011 : You may want to read ch 14 of the tcolorbox manual, "Library theorems", but the short answer is yes. The longer and more correct answer would probably be - it depends on how you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

(I wanted to comment this since it's a shameless plug, but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet.)

**[Self-promotion warning]** I recently wrote a class for doing exactly what you want! You can find it on GitHub [here](https://github.com/artemmavrin/latex-homework). Documentation and examples are included there as well.